# python bokeh error with output_file in class

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I have a probleme using bokeh in a class.

The following code is runing when i use the object "Graph" in the same file (.py), but not when i'm calling the class from an other file, and i don't know why.

```
class Graph():

    import pandas as pd

    from bokeh.models import HoverTool

    from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, ColumnDataSource

    def __init__(self, df, indicators=None):

        self.df = df

        self.output_file("test.html" , title='test')

        ....
```

I have the following error:

```
TypeError: output_file() got multiple values for argument 'title'
```

Does anybody know how can I fix it?

For information, the following code:

```
class Graph():

    import pandas as pd

    from bokeh.models import HoverTool

    from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, ColumnDataSource

    def __init__(self, df, indicators=None):

        self.df = df

        self.output_file("test.html")

        ....
```

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Documents/Programmation/python/Trade/Indicators.py", line 50, in <module>
a = TradeGraph(df)
  File "/Users/Alex/Documents/Programmation/python/Graph.py", line 29, in __init__
self.output_file("test.html")
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bokeh/io/output.py", line 77, in output_file
root_dir=root_dir
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bokeh/io/state.py", line 166, in output_file
if os.path.isfile(filename):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
st = os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not Graph
```

and the following code:

```
class Graph():

    import pandas as pd

    from bokeh.models import HoverTool

    from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, ColumnDataSource

    def __init__(self, df, indicators=None):

        self.df = df

        self.output_file()

        ....
```

returns the same (last) error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have evidently defined a method `output_file` on your own class, and that is where the problem is. (As an aside, please always try to ask questions with *complete* minimal code). Based on the output above, the most likely explanation is that you have forgotten to add the `self` parameter that Python methods should always have. That is, you have something like:

```
class Graph(object):

    def output_file(title):
```

when you need something like:

```
class Graph(object):

    def output_file(self, title):
```

However, I would question the value of having an `output_file` method at all. Unless you are doing something out of the ordinary, you should just call Bokeh's `output_file` function directly. However, please also note that `output_file` activates a *persistent implicit mode*. That is useful especially in interactive environments, but may not be in a program that saves lots of things. There is also a `save` function that just gives you explicit control wherever you want to perform a save.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answer,

I finnaly import each need module in each methode.

I thought i could all import them one time beteween the class definition and the class initialisation, but doesn't work,

Thanks